# jQuery .replaceWith freezes in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, while-loop

Today i was coding and i tried something out with the `while` loop and jQuery `.replaceWith` but then the loop never stopped and i don't know why.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="x"></div><div class="x"></div><div class="x"></div>
```

and here is my javascript code:

```
while($(".x").length !== 0) {
 $(".x:nth-child(1)").replaceWith('<div id="x"></div>');
}
```

This code freezes the browser but i don't know why.

I also tried this:

```
while($(".x").length !== 0) {
 $(".x:nth-child(1)").remove();
}
```

and that works.

What i want to do is replace all elements with class `.x` with `<div id="x"></div>`

Any idea what was going wrong in my code?

Comment: IDs must be unique, do you want to invalidate the document?

Comment: in ``replacewith`` it will never exit while loop

Comment: `$(".x:nth-child(1)")` will only find the first `<div class="x"></div>` (with your HTML), so the `.length` will always be 2 after that first replacement (which is obviously `!== 0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it using `$.each()`, the way you are doing while loop will never exit as condition will always remain `true`.

and the way you are doing will wipe content of divs.

```
$(".x").each(function() {
 $(this).removeClass("x"); // remove class x
 $(this).prop("id","x");  // add id x
});
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/04tdd2s9/

### NOTE:

Note that i have demonstrated how you can do this, but in general id of every element must be unique.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `.x:nth-child(1)` matches the element with class `x` which is the first child of his parent.

In your first case, you replace the first match with another element, so other elements of class `x` won't be the first child of its parent.

In your second code, you remove them, so the next element with class `x` will be the first child.

Moreover,

- Avoid using `$` in loops. Searching the DOM is expensive, better store the result in a variable before the loop.
- You can just test `.length` instead of `.length !== 0`
- Avoid creating elements from static strings in a loop. You can create it before and clone it inside the loop.
- To iterate all elements that match a selector, better use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- Be careful when setting `id`s, they must be unique in the document.

Comment: Embarrassingly, I had to walk through it in a debugger to realize that. **sigh** Could have just gotten a cup of coffee instead and come back to see your answer. :-) (Or, you know, remembered what `:nth-child` really means.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haha, embarrassingly I wanted to suggest `:nth-of-type` because I didn't remember exactly what it does.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that's freezing up is that you're looping for as long as you have `.x` elements, but inside your loop, you're only ever going to replace **one** of them, because the selector `.x:nth-child(1)` will only match an element if it has class `x` **and** it's the first element in its parent element. It doesn't pick the first `.x` element. So you replace the first, then loop endlessly not doing replacements at all.

You'd be better off using `each`:

```
$(".x").each(function() {
  $('<div id="x"></div>').replace(this);
});
```

That's assuming you really need to *replace* the elements, as opposed to simply removing the class and assigning an `id` to them. If that's all you need to do, [Ehsan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25221148/157247) has you covered.

---

But be sure to give each one a different `id`. Only **one** element in a document is allowed to have a given `id` value.